# Suitelet - redirect page to custom transaction form

Tags: javascript, netsuite, suitescript, test-suite, clientscript

I am new to Suitelet. I have created button called `RMA` in sales order form and created custom transaction form called `RMA-Closed`.

I want to redirect to transaction form when I click the button.

Could anyone help me how to achieve this?

Comment: improved explanation

Answer (score 0):

You can add a client script on the button and set following navigation url:

```
/app/accounting/transactions/salesord.nl?cf=132
```

where `132` can be repalced with the form id you have created.

Comment: I did by open in new window  using windows.open(). Thanks for the comment

Comment: I have next question. How to get custom fields value which is in journal entry sublist? I know its using nlapigetLineItemValue API. But I don't know about the parameter inside it.